# How can I restart the Windows 10 emoji panel process?

Tags: windows-10, process, bug, emoji-keyboard

Windows 10 emoji panel sometimes glitches out and opens empty for me. All hits (keyboard or mouse) register just fine but the window itself is never drawn on screen, just the chrome around it.

[image: Windows 10 Emoji Panel fails to render]

Which process can I restart in an attempt to fix this visual glitch without having to restart Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restarting `explorer.exe` solved the issue.

[image: Windows 10 Emoji Panel working again after restarting explorer.exe]